DotNet8 WebApi - Newly added controllers with [Authorize] attribute always returns 401 even if user is authorized
I have an existing Web Api project which works well, I can authorize and run the endpoints in controllers. But when I add a new controller and decorate with [Authorize] attribute as same as others, no matter user is authorized or not, it gives 401 error. When I comment out the [Authorize] decoration, it is accessible. But this situation occurs only on newly added controllers.  Even an empty controller. How to solve the problem?
app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseHangfireDashboard();
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllers();
    endpoints.MapGet("/", context => 
        context.Response.WriteAsync("Welcome")
    );
    
    AddHealthChecks(endpoints);
}); 


Show us your Startup/Configure code. What authorization set-up do you have? Do you have a default scheme defined? Any policies?

At least post your middleware pipeline please

From Configure method part of the code is like below:
        app.UseAuthorization();
        app.UseHangfireDashboard();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
            endpoints.MapGet("/", context => context.Response.WriteAsync("Welcome"));
            AddHealthChecks(endpoints);
        });

The problem is in any existing controllers everything work as expected. I don't have any filter for controllers as well.

It turned out that Postman request didn't have credentials set as other requests. Works as expected.
